# Не записываются данные в БД

Tags: php, mysql, request

Проблема в том, что запрос в `action.php` выполняется, но таблица не обновляется, ошибок также не выводится.

Folder/user.php:

```
....
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group label-floating">
    <form class="form-inline" action="../folder/action.php" method="post">
      <input type="number" class="form-control input-sm" name="days" placeholder="Days" style="width: 70px;" required>
      <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="reason" placeholder="Reason" required>
      <input type="hidden" name="userid" value="'.$id.'">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-simple btn-round btn-xs" name="action" value="Do action">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
....
```

Folder/action.php:

```
<?php
  include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/configuration/main.php'; // главные настройки, включающие подключение, с ними все ок

  if ($_SESSION['admin']<3) exit(redirect("../folder/",2)); // проверка сессии, выход при условии

  $mysqli=connect(); // подключение к бд

  $id=$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['userid']);
  $days=$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['days']);
  $actiontime=time()+(3600*24)*$days;
  $reason=$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['reason']);
  // ^ преобразование информации из folder/user.php

  if ($id<1||$days<0) exit(redirect("../folder/",2));

  if ($days>'0') 
     $mysqli->query("insert into `action`(`userid`,`actionid`,`reason`,`time`) values ('".$id."','".$_SESSION['id']."','".$reason."','".$actiontime."')");
  else 
     $mysqli->query("insert into `action`(`userid`,`actionid`,`reason`,`time`) values ('".$id."','".$_SESSION['id']."','".$reason."','0')");
// запросы шредингера

  $mysqli->close(); // закрытие подключения к бд
  redirect("../folder/user?id=".$id."",2); // возврат к folder/user.php
?>
```

Если скрипт выполнятся, он редиректит как и должен (последняя строка в `action.php`), но таблица `action` не содержит изменений.

Проверил все переменные, все они выводятся верно. Подключение к БД также верно.

Comment: Что возвращает функция `$mysqli->query`?

Comment: А вы проовали вместо всего-то этого просто от руки написать запрос К БД на добавление с рандомными данными? Т.е. чтобы скрипт просто выполнял жёстко написанный запрос к БД?

Comment: @n.osennij, да, само собой. Результат тот же.

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, выполняет запрос??

Comment: @n.osennij, пробовал инсерт в только что созданную, новую таблицу, запрос сработал. Что не так с таблицей `action` ума не приложу.

Comment: советую обратить внимание на [SafeMySQL](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql)

Comment: Еще раз, `$mysqli->query` это **функция** и она возвращает какой-то результат? Какой?

Comment: Не пишите «решено» в заголовках. Решение вопроса отмечается зелёной галочкой возле ответа, который помог

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Советую написать sql запрос в каком-нибудь редакторе и выполнить его там же (хоть phpMyAdmin). Если данные запишутся, пробуйте выполнить тот же запрос на стороне php. Если ок, то копайте дальше поэтапно.

Рекомендую вообще использовать PDO (чтобы забыть про sql инъекции) или какую-нибудь библиотеку для удобной работы. А, и добавление и т.п. с базой нужно через транзакции делать.

```
$connection->autocommit(false); 
    $query = ""; //sql query here
    $result = $connection->query($query);
    if (!$result) exit($connection->error);
if (!$connection->commit()) exit($connection->error);
```

Ну и чем писать так `values ('".$id."',` , можно сделать красивее и удобнее вот так `values ('${id}',` или `values ('$id',`. Но первый вариант чуточку быстрее.

Comment: Проблема оказалась в отсутствии автоинкримента у одного из столбов.